# Craft 3: Front End Entry Form

Tags: craft3, entry-form

I am following the documentation for Craft 2 [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form) to create an entry form on the front end of my website. The form appears correctly on the front end but when I submit it, I get the following error: 
"Page not found.
Caused by: Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException
Unable to resolve the request: entries/saveEntry"

Here's my form:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="news/{slug}">
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="1">

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="">

    <label for="body">Body</label>
    <textarea id="body" name="fields[body]" rows="20"></textarea>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here? The user I am currently using to submit the form is an admin. I realize that the docs I'm following are for Craft 2 but I could not find this form in the Craft 3 docs.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Craft 3 uses kebab-case paths instead of camelCase paths
Your action parameter must be `entries/save-entry`

Its all stated in the [docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html#action-params)

Edit: generally a good idea is to inspect the html in your cp form and copy it to your frontend. You'll be able to solve 90% of your issues that way

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: Thank you - I replaced it with the new one